# How to make vim truly reopen a file as a cpp file?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have a file `filename.fs` with C-like syntax content. Vim opens it as a Forth source, and I use `:set syntax=cpp` to get the correct highlighting. But later when I try to jump between words I encounter that almost every set of chars is a word, so `w` goes almost always to end of line or so. I figured that this is related to `iskeyword` setting, and `:verbose set iskeyword?` gives me

```
iskeyword=!,@,33-35,%,$,38-64,A-Z,91-96,a-z,123-126,128-255
       Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/forth.vim
```

So this appears to be also because of Forth-like suffix. I try doing `set filetype=cpp`, but this doesn't bring me the usual value of `isk` like `@,48-57,_,192-255`. It appears that the usual `*.cpp`-specific is set from `/usr/share/vim/vim74/debian.vim`, so it's not dependent on the file being `cpp`. But if I do e.g. `:e newfile.cpp`, then `isk` does get set to this default value even if before this I was editing a `*.fs` file.

So, my question is, how do I (re-)open my `*.fs` file as a non-Forth file, but without breaking the defaults for real Forth files and without need to manually set `isk` to the desired value?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `:setlocal filetype=cpp` instead of `:set syntax=cpp`, but that still doesn't help you here.

---

The problem is that `'iskeyword'` is set in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/forth.vim`, but it doesn't use the `b:undo_ftplugin` mechanism to undo that when the filetype changes (to `cpp`), so the modified option persists.

#### Fix A

If you never need to edit `*.fs` files as Forth, you can override the default *filetype detection*. Basically, create a file `~/.vim/filetype.vim` with the following contents:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    au BufNewFile,BufRead *.fs         setf cpp
augroup END
```

See `:help filetype-detect` (and following paragraphs) for details. This is the most efficient setup.

#### Fix B

Alternatively, you can correct the omission by the syntax script via a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/forth.vim` with these contents:

```
let b:undo_ftplugin = 'setlocal iskeyword<'
```

Comment: `setlocal isk<` does work after I do `set filetype=cpp`, but writing your full command to `~/.vim/ftplugin/forth.vim` doesn't seem to automatically call this. Do I misunderstand what it actually should do?

Comment: Do you have `:filetype plugin on` in your `.vimrc`? Without it you have to write `autocmd FileType forth let b:undo_ftplugin ...` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: No, I don't, and when I tried adding it, it didn't seem to change anything...